# Encountering ClassNotFoundException when trying to use Ring Jetty alongside Cognitect AWS-api in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, jetty, ring, compojure

I'm building a Ring-Jetty/Compojure app and there a situation where I have to interact with the AWS S3 API. So I decided to use Cognitect's [aws-api](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/aws-api) for that. However, I'm encountering an issue when using it alongside Compojure with the Ring-Jetty adapter where it all just crashes down. When I remove the aws-api dependencies, these errors go away. I can't seem to figure out what the conflict is though. Can somebody help me out?

[The exception](https://pastebin.com/xGUDzr0E)

My `project.clj`:

```
(defproject my-app-server "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [compojure "1.6.1"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.3.2"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.5"]
                 [ring/ring-anti-forgery "1.3.0"]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "1.0.0"]
                 [seancorfield/next.jdbc "1.1.547"]
                 [honeysql "1.0.444"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "42.2.14"]
                 [crypto-password "0.2.1"]
                 [com.taoensso/carmine "2.19.1"]
                 [com.novemberain/langohr "5.1.0"]
                 [com.cognitect.aws/api "0.8.469"]
                 [com.cognitect.aws/endpoints "1.1.11.826"]
                 [com.cognitect.aws/s3 "799.2.682.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.12.5"]]
  :ring {:handler my-app-server.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring/ring-mock "0.3.2"]]}})
```

Comment: Perhaps you could try adding the adapter as an explicit dependency: `[ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.8.1"]`

Comment: It could be a bootstrap state being created by the aws-api. I recommend using a dependency library to organize the bootstrap order for each dependency (I prefer mount over component). I've had similar boot problems and organizing the bootstrap solved it. As you are also using carmine and jdbc, there is some complex state setup going on during the boot of your app

Comment: @jaihindhreddy Thank you! This worked.

Comment: @andriosr Thanks, will do this.

Comment: Note `ring-jetty-adapter` version 1.8.1 uses Servlet 3.1.0 (not 2.5)

Comment: @jaihindhreddy go ahead and make a formal answer for your comment.  We'll vote you up. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`ClassNotFound` exception usually means the right dependency is not on the classpath, or there's a typo in what you're trying to `require`. In this case, the `ring-jetty-adapter` lib was missing. Because you're using leiningen, you can add `[ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.8.1"]` to your `:dependencies` to fix it.

`lein classpath` and `lein deps :tree` are useful tools to debug things like this.